# JSON.NET serialization issue with protected property setter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a base class, `BaseRecord`, with an `int` property, `RecordTypeId`, that holds an `enum` value for the a record's type.

```
public class BaseRecord
{
    public int RecordTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

**If `set` is made `protected`**

```
    public int RecordTypeId { get; protected set; }
```

**then `RecordTypeId` becomes *0* after construction, regardless of the value passed in?**

```
public class ChildRecord : BaseRecord
{
    public int RecordId { get; set; }

    public ChildRecord( int recordTypeId, int recordId )
    {
        RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;
        RecordId = recordId;
    }
}
```

Since `RecordTypeId` is only set in a constructor, and is only used by a data access layer, I figured to make it `protected`.

Comment: The code as presented should work. There is nothing wrong as far as I can see. Can you please post an MCVE which reproduces the issue? (also, as a sidenote, if you're going to be storing an enum in this field, use the enum type. No point in obfuscating your intentions, and enums can always be cast to an int when you need to)

Comment: @Flater I will try, though I did verify that all the tables that the records get serialized to are exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: I suspect that the code you posted must have a maybe small but critical difference to your actual code. for example, your post has `int` as the type not enum. Did you maybe also omit a constructor chain?

Comment: @samosaris: Then the serialization could be at fault here too. (Note that most serializations I know of always use a **parameterless** constructor - which could explain the issue) Test the class itself in a simple console application to confirm the problem is actually occurring in the class definition.

Comment: Yeah I am not understanding the question.  Are you saying that your code _always_ sets `RecordTypeId` to 0 no matter what you pass in to the `ChildRecord` constructor?  Because that should not happen at all, and the code you have posted will not behave like you claim

Comment: "get serialized to" New information. Are you saying you're seeing this behavior when trying to *deserialize* the object? That's a completely different question and is the expected behavior.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Flater storing explicitly as a `enum` instead of an `int` is on the todo list.

Comment: @maccettura Sounds like you are, yeah :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you mentioned that this happens after **deserialization**.

You did not specify which serializer you're using; but every serializer I know of always works based on a **parameterless constructor** and **publically settable properties**.
The serializer creates an object (`var newObj = new T();` where T is generic) and then, for each property in the serialized data, tries to set the property on `newObj`.

Since the serializer does not inherit from `BaseRecord`, it has no access to the `protected` properties of the `BaseRecord.`

> **From the comments below**
>   Think of the serializer as a separate class. It can access a `BaseRecord`'s public properties, and set their value (if the setter is public). But if the setter is protected, then an external class (the serializer) is unable to set the value. What's inside the JSON data doesn't matter, it's about whether the serializer (an external class) is allowed to set the value of the property or not.
>   You'll see that a class with properties marked as `public get; protected set;` can be serialized **to** JSON (because the getter is public) but not deserialized **from** JSON (because the setter is not public).

---

> Since RecordTypeId is only set in a constructor, **and is only used by a data access layer**, I figured to make it protected.

Is it possible that you are confusing `protected` with `internal`?

`Protected` is only accessible by those who inherit. `Internal` is accessble by everyone in the same assembly (project). Your description here seems to suggest that you're trying to do the latter.

> **From the comments below:**
>   Keep in mind that JSON.NET is in an assembly of its own, so even `internal` access won't work since this is going across assembly borders.

Comment: I'm using JSON.NET (Newtonsoft.Json)... I will post more info next time, thanks.

Comment: @samosaris: Keep in mind that JSON.NET is in an assembly of its own, so even `internal` access won't work since this is going across assembly borders.

Comment: I didn't suspect the serializer to be the problem since the values are non-zero when examining them within the json data returned from the web server. For some reason it happens during deserialization only... like you stated.

Comment: @samosaris: Think of the serializer as a separate class. It can access a `BaseRecord`'s public properties, and set their value (if the setter is public). But if the setter is protected, then an external class (the serializer) is unable to set the value. What's inside the JSON data doesn't matter, it's about whether the serializer (an external class) is allowed to set the value of the property or not. You'l see that properties marked as `public get; protected set;` can be serialized **to** JSON (because the getter is public) but not deserialized **from JSON** (because the setter is not public)

Comment: Was this a design decision based on performance, b/c I'm suspecting reflection is being used to enumerate an object's properties in order to set them? There's no efficient way to call a non-default constructor, I mean, the type information of each property/member is already encoded in the deserialized object's data correct? How much more computationally intensive could it be to generate a constructor call and "dynamically" invoke it, per say (I think even C can invoke/execute string data on the fly if I remember correctly)?

Comment: @samosaris `I'm suspecting reflection is being used to enumerate an object's properties in order to set them?` Reflection is used during _serialization_, where the serializer loops over the object's properties. But keep in mind that this is different for **deserialization**. In deserialization, the serializer loops over the **JSON properties** and then sets the object's properties based on that. It doesn't actually need to "discover" the object properties. And, as I already mentioned, if the getter of your property were protected instead of public, you couldn't serialize the data either.

Comment: @samosaris: The above comment is simplified for brevity's sake. I've made a few shorthand statement in order to fit it in a comment. It is not correct in excruciating detail, but it does show why your assumption isn't correct.